# PostgreSQL OVERLAPS operator returning a false positive

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query

```sql
SELECT ('2022-08-21T22:30:00.000Z'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '1 hour'::INTERVAL) 
        OVERLAPS ('2022-08-21 18:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '1 hour'::INTERVAL);
```

and it seems to be returning true. I'm not sure why
[image]

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1e2156b1fedcb37754e178a29bf568af

Comment: Hmm, returns false [in dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c4eb10a6892096ed4091d7ee5e781920) and on my [local Postgres](https://i.imgur.com/ph5uFbI.png)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What version of Postgres are you using? This happens for me in both 11 and 13

Comment: Postgres 14, but dbfiddle with [Postgres 11](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c4eb10a6892096ed4091d7ee5e781920) and [Postgres 13](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c4eb10a6892096ed4091d7ee5e781920) also returns false

Comment: What's the time zone of the second interval? You seem to have forgotten to include it...

Comment: Yeah, the timezone was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [The Impaler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436191/the-impaler)

`What's the time zone of the second interval? You seem to have forgotten to include it...`